# How to resolve "TypeError: form.addEventListner is not a function"

Tags: javascript, web

I am in the process of learning web development and was building an frontend app when got this error from my script.js. I'm not sure how to go about resolving it.(the html file has a form that takes input as movie name to fetch all the movies from the api.

```
   form.addEventListener("submit",(e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   main.innerHTML =''

   const searchItem = search.value ;
   if (searchItem){
     returnMovies(SEARCHAPI+searchItem);
     search.value ="";
   }
 });
```

this is where i am getting the error
and the following is the entire script.js file

```
const APILINK = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=a51be54af06c91b914fc566261c23fd3&page=1';
const IMG_PATH='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280';
const SEARCHAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?&api_key=a51be54af06c91b914fc566261c23fd3&query=";


const main = document.getElementById("section");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const search = document.getElementById("query")

returnMovies(APILINK);

function returnMovies(url){
  fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()).then(function(data){
    console.log(data.results);
    data.results.forEach(element=>{
      const div_card = document.creatEelement('div');
      div_card.setAttribute('class','card');
      
      const div_row = document.creatEelement('div');
      div_card.setAttribute('class','row');
      
      const div_column = document.creatEelement('div');
      div_card.setAttribute('class','column');
      
      const image = document.creatEelement('img');
      div_card.setAttribute('class','thumbnail');
      div_card.setAttribute('id','image');
      
      const title = document.creatEelement('h3');
      div_card.setAttribute('id','title');
      
      const center = document.creatEelement('center');

      title.innerHTML = `${element.title}`
      image.src = IMG_PATH + element.poster_path;
      center.appendChild(image);
      div_card.appendChild(center);
      div_card.appendChild(title);
      div_column.appendChild(div_card);
      div_row.appendChild(div_column);

      main.appendChild(div_row);
    });
  });
}

form.addEventListener("submit",(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  main.innerHTML =''

  const searchItem = search.value ;
  if (searchItem){
    returnMovies(SEARCHAPI+searchItem);
    search.value ="";
  }
});
```

I tried looking for solutions over here but wasn't able to understand any of them as they weren't that beginner friendly.

Comment: Did you run the javascript file directly? You have to link the js file to html, by doing (in your html file) `<script src="my/path/to/script.js"></script>`. You don't run the javascript file directly.

Comment: This is usually caused because your script is executing before the page has created the elements. Since we can't see your HTML, we can't verify it, but either move your script to right before the closing `</body>` tag or wrap it in `window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded`, ... )` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: In the first line of your `returnMovies` function, you mispelled `res.json`. You wrote `res.jason`

Comment: Did you give all elements an id? Like this: `<tagName id="whateverMyIdIs">Whatever my Content is</tagName>`

Comment: I fixed the spelling , thanks @WOWOW still there is no change , the error doesn't show up but the api isn't fetching the data either, not able to see anything on the webpage

Comment: You haven't fixed it in the question

Comment: You use `fetch(url)`, but `url` is not defined anywhere in your file

Comment: I rectified that as well but the website still doesn't seem to work

Comment: wrap all your code in `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { /* your code */ });`

Comment: the entire script file ?

Comment: Yes, the entire script. _Or_ move your `<script>` tag to _after_ all the elements have been declared. Scripts get executed in line, so if your element definition in HTML comes after your script, your script can't actually find the element and you would get the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the HTML document to be loaded into the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM). The following example is structured so that is fits your case. You have a JavaScript file (script.js) that is referenced in the HTML head element using a script element. So, the script element is actually rendered before the content because it comes first. At that point the browser don't know about the rest of the document, therefore you need an event listener listening for the `DOMContentLoaded` event (there are also other ways, never mind). In the callback function of that event listener you can then pick out the elements that you need to refer to and make the event listener for the submit event on the form.

```js
const APILINK = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=a51be54af06c91b914fc566261c23fd3&page=1';
const IMG_PATH = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280';
const SEARCHAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?&api_key=a51be54af06c91b914fc566261c23fd3&query=";

var main;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  main = document.getElementById("section");
  let form = document.forms.form01;

  returnMovies(APILINK);

  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    main.innerHTML = '';
    returnMovies(SEARCHAPI + e.target.search.value);
  });
});

function returnMovies(url) {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.results);
    data.results.forEach(element => {
      const div_card = document.creatEelement('div');
      div_card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

      const div_row = document.creatEelement('div');
      div_card.setAttribute('class', 'row');

      const div_column = document.creatEelement('div');
      div_card.setAttribute('class', 'column');

      const image = document.creatEelement('img');
      div_card.setAttribute('class', 'thumbnail');
      div_card.setAttribute('id', 'image');

      const title = document.creatEelement('h3');
      div_card.setAttribute('id', 'title');

      const center = document.creatEelement('center');

      title.innerHTML = `${element.title}`
      image.src = IMG_PATH + element.poster_path;
      center.appendChild(image);
      div_card.appendChild(center);
      div_card.appendChild(title);
      div_column.appendChild(div_card);
      div_row.appendChild(div_column);

      main.appendChild(div_row);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form01">
    <input type="text" name="search" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  <section id="section"></section>
</body>

</html>
```